# UITextView Scrolls to the right when it gains focus in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Whenever I tap on my `UITextView` on my testing device, the text is pushed far to the right as demonstrated in the gif below.

[image: text field forced to the right]

I can't see why this behaviour is happening, within my Storyboard I have tried to disable scrolling and have applied constraints to ensure that the width of the `UITextView` is only ever the width of the device, yet this still happens. The `UITextView` has not been subclassed or had any additional attributes applied to it via code.

If anybody has had this problem before it would be great to get some insight around how I could remedy it.

**EDIT** Constraints for the text view.

[image: Shows constraints for text view]

Comment: Would you mind posting a screenshot showing the constraints attached to the `UITextView`?

Comment: Sure - will upload now.

Comment: @CeceXX you should note that only the width constraint is applied to the TextView